# I can't open secured PDF in Ubuntu (open password), but can in Windows XP

Tags: 14.04, password, encryption, pdf, windows-xp

I can open a certain PDF in Windows XP like any other, but I can't open the same PDF in Ubuntu because I get asked for "open password".

In XP Foxit reader shows that the file is secured for all clauses except for content copying, but the file opens and is accessible without having to enter any password.

What is the problem and how can I open the file in Ubuntu?

Comment: Which PDF reader were you using? I use a Windows port of Evince, and it recently asked for a password to open a document. One of my colleagues looked into this, and found that a password was required to *edit* the document, but not to open it. This suggested that Evince was simply checking if a password was required for anything at all, and then assuming incorrectly that the password was needed to open it as well.

Answer (score 1):

The PDF viewer `evince` should be able to open a protected PDF files when they do not need a password. To test the various capabilities of the PDF viewers available to you you can simply download [example PDF test files](https://www.novapdf.com/pdf-example-files-created-with-novapdf-kb.html) from novapdf.com. If you take for example the first file you can open it without any password.

Besides using `evince` there is also the possibility of trying to remove the password on the command line using various tools. A good article about [How To Remove PDF Password Protection](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/removing-password-from-pdf-on-linux/) can be read at cyberciti.biz.

Comment: Crap, I totally forgot about this question. Today I needed to use the file and encountered the problem again. I remember reading somewhere that this has something to do with how Windows and Ubuntu handle some certificates. That's why I can open the file in Windows without being asked for a password at all and read it without any problems, while I can't read the file in Ubuntu - since I have no idea what the password is and evince asks me to provide one. I can also upload the same file to Google Drive and read it with their viewer w/o being asked for a password. Only w/ Ubuntu I get this prob.

Comment: Two of the command lines from the cyberciti link in this answer worked for me, creating a PDF that I could open in Evince. The first was `qpdf --decrypt in.pdf out.pdf`. The second had to be altered for more recent versions of Ghostscript, but once that was done, `gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf in.pdf` also worked. However, the `gs` command line wouldn't accept an output file path with the `~` character in, and the output file itself was much larger than the qpdf version.

Answer (score 0):

Normally Ubuntu will ask for root password in order to open applications. similar to administrator password asking scenario during application run in windows 7 and I believe that it is not related to some other issue. try providing root password and check. If you are getting any issue or error message after providing correct root password then kn idly share the error to get clear picture of the issue.

If it is password protected and you forgot the password use pdfcrack and check

Install pdfcrack in Ubuntu and check if you are able to open it up!

```
sudo aptitude install pdfcrack
```

Comment: I totally forgot about this question. Today I needed to use the file and encountered the problem again. I remember reading somewhere that this has something to do with how Windows and Ubuntu handle some certificates. That's why I can open the file in Windows without being asked for a password at all and read it without any problems, while I can't read the file in Ubuntu - since I have no idea what the password is and evince asks me to provide one. Pdfcrack can't handle the pdf in question. Besides, it would take too much to crack it.